# How much of the code have been ran in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

When a heavy code is running in Matlab, is there any way to determine how much of the code have been ran till now? (How many percent)

Comment: Do you mean if say 80% of the code has been reached during runs and 20% sits there idly, or do you mean "you have finished 50% of the thing" while the code is running? Former is done using profiler, later can be faked somewhat using a debugger that lets you pause during execution at arbitrary point when you want to. Then you need to manually estimate/calculate how much you still need to do.

Comment: I ran the code about two hours ago and it is still running. I want to know how much more time I need so that the running process finish. @ZizyArcher

Answer (score 1):

You should pause the program, manually calculate how much is there still to go and decide whether to wait for it or give up.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

> Pause a Running File
>
> To pause the execution of a program while it is running, go to the Editor tab and click the Pause button. MATLAB pauses execution at the next executable line, and the Pause button changes to a Continue button. To continue execution, press the Continue button.
>
> Pausing is useful if you want to check on the progress of a long running program to ensure that it is running as expected.
>
> Note:   Clicking the pause button can cause MATLAB to pause in a file outside your own program file. Pressing the Continue button resumes normal execution without changing the results of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have an iterative process on where the time of each iteration will take approximately the same time (not always the case, but often this happens) then you can use this to know when will the code end:

```
for ii=1:niter
    if (ii==1); tic; end

    % your iteration

    if (ii==1);
        expected_time=toc*niter;
        disp('Myalgorithm');
        disp(['Expected duration  :    ',secs2hms(expected_time)]);
        disp(['Exected finish time:    ',datestr(datetime('now')+seconds(expected_time))]);
        disp('');
    end
end
```

Using [`sec2hms`](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22817-seconds-to-hours--minutes--seconds/content/secs2hms.m) from FEX.

This code prints the following:

```
Myalgorithm
Expected duration  :    41.0 secs
Exected finish time:    28-Mar-2017 10:58:57
```

Comment: I ran my code about two hours ago and it is still running. I want to know how much more time I need so that the running process finish.

Comment: @OliverRange once you started running the code, you can not know how long it will take. You need to prepare your code to tell you before you run it.

Comment: Oh, I see :( :(

Comment: If I post my code in the question, could you please tell me if your answer could work for it or not?

Comment: This works if you have 1)an iterative code, 2)that takes more or less the same time per iteration. You can check that yourself! @OliverRange

Comment: But I cannot do that because I have started running the code and I cannot stop it. Also, I don't know what is a iterative code?

Comment: @OliverRange you can google it..... Iterative code: code that has iterations, i.e. a log for loop or while loop. Again, if you have started running your code, there is nothing you can do to know when it will stop. If it takes long time I suggest you stop it and try to estimate how low it will take. Long/badly written code can take months to run.